# wxPython change frames on button clicks

Tags: python-2.7, button, wxpython

I have just started programming with wxPython today, and I need some help.
I just want to understand how to write a code with a few buttons, and if a button is pressed another screen shows.
For example, there are 2 buttons: "log in" and "sign up".
if "log in is pressed", the user needs to enter username and password into a text box, if "sign up" is pressed, the user needs to give his name, email and password in text boxes.
How can I do it?
By the way, I just don't know how to start, I will need many states (such as "log in" and "sign up") in the future.
And another question, what names should I give each class, I saw "MyApp", "My Frame" and a lot more, and I don't understand where does the "app.MainLoop()" is really looping, in which class, where?
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.01/wxPython-demo-4.0.1.tar.gz Research using the wxpython demo programs